# Actualizar datos de SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo mi codigo realizando una inserción de datos a mi BD, hasta aquí todo bien pero al realizar una actualización de datos para machacar todo la información y que solo en mi BD muestre el ultimo dato. Me encontraría en un callejon sin salida al no tener los conocimientos suficientes. Podría descartar el insert into de mi codigo o debería seguir usandolo??

```
protected void Button_Arranque(object sender, EventArgs e){

    string sql = string.Empty;
    string loginValidado = string.Empty;
    string error = string.Empty;
    string MensajeValidacion = string.Empty;
    try
  {          
       // Valido el usuario  
    if (validarUsuario.validarU(this.variableAuxiliarUser.Text.Trim(), this.variableAuxiliarPass.Text.Trim(),
    this.variableAuxiliarPin.Text.Trim(),Ets.ReportID, out loginValidado, out error))

    {
      //Mensaje_Generico.Mostra_Mensaje(this.Page, "El Login es correcto" ,Conversor.convertirString(Titulo_Mensajes.Correcto),Conversor.convertirEnumInt(Tipo_Mensajes.Correcto));
      sql= @" insert into _EBR_Estado_Lineas (Sistema, Referencia, [OF], Lote, Inicio, Usuario, velocidad, Estado) values ({0}, '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', getDate(),  '{4}', '{5}', '{6}') 
             select  @@IDENTITY as ID;";                
      sql = string.Format(sql,this.SistemaID, this.txtReferencia.Text.ToString(), this.txtOF.Text.ToString(), 
            this.txtLote.Text.ToString(), this.variableAuxiliarUser.Text.Trim(), this.txtvelocidad.Text, this.estado.ToString());              
      DataTable dt = this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.GetDataTable(sql).Return;

      if ((dt != null) && (dt.Rows.Count == 1)) 
      { this.sDatos = Conversor.convertirString(dt.Rows[0]["ID"]); }

    }
    else
      {
        Mensaje_Generico.Mostra_Mensaje(this.Page,Conversor.convertirString(error), Conversor.convertirString(Titulo_Mensajes.Error),Conversor.convertirEnumInt(Tipo_Mensajes.Error));              
      }

     this.Response.Redirect(string.Format("../../webtrak/report/view.aspx?ReportKey=CNTR_TIEMPO&Prueba=3&sDatos={0}",sDatos));
  }        
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      Log.insertarComentario("","error al añadir los campos", ex.Message.ToString());

   }   

  }
```

Sería algo:

```
 sql= @"update _EBR_Estado_Lineas SET Sistema='{0}', Referencia= '{1}', [OF]='{2}'....)
```

Answer (score 0):

No acabo de entender lo que pretendes

> Tengo mi codigo realizando una inserción de datos a mi BD, hasta aquí todo bien

Correcto, es lo que vemos en el código que nos muestras. Insertas un registro de un usuario

> pero al realizar una actualización de datos para machacar todo la información y que solo en mi BD muestre el ultimo dato.

Entiendo que lo que no te conviene es que la segunda vez que la aplicación realice otro insert para este usuario.

Si es este el caso, lo que debes hacer es un `SELECT` previo para ver si ya existe el registro.

```
SELECT Usuario from _EBR_Estado_Lineas
```

Si no hay registro, realizas el `insert`, si lo hay haces un `update`.
Otra opción es la de realizar siempre un `delete` de ese usuario (no pasa nada si no existe) y luego siempre el `insert`

Comment: Si esta eso estaría correcto, con update podría borrar todos los datos indiferentemente del usuario que haya echo el proceso.??